# cin crashes C++ program

Tags: c++

I feel like this is a very rudimentary problem, but I can't seem to get cin working.

Using code as simple as this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int i;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> i;   
    cout << i;
}
```

causes the program to crash. It compiles perfectly fine, but when I run it I get the program has stopped working dialog box. I'm using MinGW with the g++ commands to compile my code. I'm also running windows 8.1 if that has any effect whatsoever.

Comment: It's technically undefined behaviour if the read fails, but a crash? I doubt it.

Comment: Make sure you're linking against the correct version of the libraries.

Comment: Yeah, this is only a hair's breadth from "Hello World."  Seems like it must be an environment / library problem?

Comment: Give the flag "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" a try

Comment: Your code is ok - this is an issue for the mingw support forum, if it's still supported (I'd recommend you consider cygwin instead).

Comment: Yeah ok, so the flag "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" makes the program just sit there forever, don't really know what it's doing. I'll try using cygwin, and see if it has a different effect.

Comment: I tried updating and nothing changed. The version of g++ installed is 4.8.1-4 I have no clue if this is the latest version or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is perfectly fine. The issue is with the compiler. This generally happens because of the misconfiguration of linking files (DLL's). It is recommended that you uninstall the current installation and re-install the software by following the installation instructions. If you are looking for bundled alternatives then you can try Code::Blocks - http://www.codeblocks.org/.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help. I reinstalled MinGW and started using Code::Blocks and now everything is working great.